# Initializing interface instance variables

Tags: interface, kotlin

I would like to inject (enrich) behavior and state in a Kotlin class by using an interface. Like `class Impl : Observable`, where Observable contains state.

In Scala using Traits (does work), looking for a Kotlin solution for this one:

```scala
object Test extends App {
  val impl = new Impl()
  val observer = new Observer()
  impl.register(observer)
}

trait Observable {
  // How to do this in Kotlin?
  val observers = List()

  def register(observer: Observer) {
    observers.add(observer)
  }
}
class Observer

class Parent
class Impl extends Parent with Observable
```

Attempt in Kotlin (not working):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val impl = Impl()
    val observer = Observer()
    impl.register(observer)
}

interface Observable {
    // Error: Kotlin: Property initializers are not allowed in interfaces
    val observers = mutableListOf<Observer>()

    fun register(observer: Observer) {
        observers.add(observer)
    }
}
class Observer

open class Parent
class Impl : Parent(), Observable
```

It results in this error at the interface instance variable line: `Kotlin: Property initializers are not allowed in interfaces`.
How can I initialize instance variables in Kotlin interfaces?
(Note that in this design, parent classes shouldn't be altered/updated.)

**UPDATE: I had an example solution in Java, but that wasn't behaving correctly. "Instance variables" in Java interfaces are automatically static. So I have removed that example.**

Comment: This is possible if you just turn it around a bit, I've added an answer because the accepted answer does not cover what you can actually do to accomplish the same goal as you are trying to achieve.  Accepting answers too quickly means you might not attract a correct answer later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a placeholder for state in Kotlin interfaces, and let the implementing class provide that state.  So the interface can provide the functionality that works against the expected-to-exist state.  Such as:

```
class Observer

interface Observable {
    val observers: MutableList<Observer> // not present, but expected

    fun register(observer: Observer) {
        observers.add(observer)
    }
}

open class Parent

class Impl : Parent(), Observable {
    override val observers = mutableListOf<Observer>() // used by the interface
}
```

This is for good reason, there are delicate issues having state coming from more than one item in the class hierarchy and Kotlin is preventing the problems that can arise from such models.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you actually have a static field, not an instance field (unlike Scala code, which does work as you expect):

> [Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html)

You can achieve the same behavior in Kotlin by putting the field into a companion object.

But what you should actually do is use an `abstract class` instead of an interface.

Or [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html):

```
interface Observable {
    fun register(observer: Observer)
}

class ObserverList : Observable {
    val observers = mutableListOf<Observer>()

    override fun register(observer: Observer) {
        observers.add(observer)
    }
}

class Impl : Parent(), Observable by ObserverList()
```

Comment: You're right about instance variables in Java interfaces being static. I have just updated my post to reflect this. But abstract classes aren't an option because the class has to extend another class that cannot be modified. So I guess "enriching" as they call it in Scala, isn't possible in Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Enriching can't add instance variables (extending a class isn't "enriching").

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov This does not solve the problem and allow the interface to support logic against state that it wants to define.  There is a way to do this in Kotlin.